# Align parts of text in a TextView

Tags: java, android, text, textview, alignment

I'm working on an Android application that receives data and should show these data in a particular way. I receive three Strings (for example A,B and C) and i have to append these to a my own created TextView, in this way :

|A    B    C|

A must be aligned to the left, B to the center and C to the right.
I really don't know how to do this ; the dimension of the TextView can changes depends on the size of the screen used to run the application, however these string must be on the position i show in every possible cases.

Thanks for help!

Ps: is it possibile to show these strings in BOLD???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Text2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Text3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) please use 3xTextView inside linearlayout, orientation horizontal

2) LinearLayout `android:width="match_parent"`

3) In text view setup `android:layout_gravity` for A) `left` B) `center` C) `right`

4) For TextView set `android:layout_weight=1`

Bold for textView: 
`android:textStyle="bold"`